# Parse cannot get the sessionToken?

Tags: php, parse-platform

I have a different login module from parse on my website server. where I want to set the **currentUser** but without password I can only do this by become method. but it requires a session token. first time when I insert to the parse then parse gave me the **sessionToken**. but after that i cannot get the **sessionToken** when i retrive the details of the user can you please help me to get the **sessionToken** in php of an old user.
Thanks in Advance

```
  $query = new ParseQuery("_User");
  $query->equalTo("username",$convertedemail);
  $res = $query->find();
  print_r($res);

ParseClient::setStorage( new ParseSessionStorage() );
        $sessiontoken = $res[0]->get("sessionToken");
        $user = ParseUser::become($sessiontoken); // need session token here to set the currentUser
```

Comment: Do you have any php code to show?

Comment: hello maxhb, I had updated the question with a sample code